# Why is crash command exiting without prompt?

Tags: centos, kdump

I've installed a debug kernel and enabled kdump. The coredump was generated successfully, but when I try to load the vmcore after reboot, crash command just quit without prompt:

```
# crash /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64.debug/vmlinux /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2019-05-25-22\:55\:50/vmcore

crash 7.2.3-8.el7
Copyright (C) 2002-2017  Red Hat, Inc.
Copyright (C) 2004, 2005, 2006, 2010  IBM Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999-2006  Hewlett-Packard Co
Copyright (C) 2005, 2006, 2011, 2012  Fujitsu Limited
Copyright (C) 2006, 2007  VA Linux Systems Japan K.K.
Copyright (C) 2005, 2011  NEC Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999, 2002, 2007  Silicon Graphics, Inc.
Copyright (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002  Mission Critical Linux, Inc.
This program is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License,
and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under
certain conditions.  Enter "help copying" to see the conditions.
This program has absolutely no warranty.  Enter "help warranty" for details.

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"...
```

Any ideas?

Is there any way to convert vmcore file to a coredump file so that I can load it directly with gdb?

Comment: crash does use gdb - it looks like you're invoking it right. check that your core has non zero size and also check the system log to see if there was an error in dumping the core.

Comment: It's not empty and the related dmesg file is fine as well.